# Best db engine for building a web app with ranking algorithms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, mongodb

I've got an idea for a new web app which will involve the following:

1.) lots of raw inputs (text values) that will be stored in a db - some of which contribute as signals to a ranking algorithm

2.) data crunching & analysis - a series of scripts will be written which together form an algorithm that will take said raw inputs from 1.) and then store a series of ranking values for these inputs.

Events 1.) and 2.) are independent of each other. Event 2 will probably happen once or twice a day. Event 1 will happen on an ongoing basis.

I initially dabbled with the idea of writing the whole thing in node.js sitting on top of mongodb as I will curious to try out something new and while I think node.js would be perfect for event 1.) I don't think it will work well for the event 2.) outlined above.

I'd also rather keep everything in one domain rather than mixing node.js with something else for step 2.

Does anyone have any recommendations for what stacks work well for computational type web apps?

Should I stick with PHP or Rails/Mysql (which I already have good experience with)?
Is MongoDB/nosql constrained when it comes to computational analysis?

Thanks for your advice,

Ed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason why node.js wouldn't work.

You would just write two node applications.

One that takes input stores it in the database and renders output

and the other one crunches numbers in it's own process and is run once or twice per day.

Of course if your doing real number crunching and you need performance you wouldn't do nr 2 in node/ruby/php. You would do it in fortran (or maybe C).

Comment: Thanks Raynos, well said. I have been giving that a good bit of thought alright - I guess actually writing my question helped me frame my problem better and your suggestion is a good one.